# issue with pagination and limit

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, limit

I have 3 tables site_settings,sermons & Preachers. In site_settings table, set the max number of preachers to be displayed. Preacher table contains all the preacher details and sermons table contains sermons of all preachers. Am using pagination for displaying preachers(2/page). if the value of site_settings table is 1 or 2 then no of preachers will display 2, if 3 or 4 then preachers 4... I don't know what is happening. Is it a problem with pagination or limit? I am using the following code for this ( In Model)

Method in Model

```
function viewAll($offset=0, $limit=null) {

        $this->db->select('settings_value');
        $this->db->from('site_settings');
        $this->db->where('settings_name', 'preachercount');
        $count = $this->db->get()->row();
        echo $count->settings_value;

        $preacher = array();
        $this->db->select('preacher.preacher_id,preacher.first_name,preacher.last_name,preacher.preacher_image,preacher.preacher_logo,preacher.preacher_bio_brief');
        $this->db->distinct('preacher.preacher_id');
        $this->db->from('preacher');
        $this->db->join('sermons', 'sermons.preacher_id=preacher.preacher_id');
        $this->db->order_by('preacher.sort_order');
        $this->db->limit($count->settings_value);
        $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_id'] = $row->preacher_id;
                $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_name'] = $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name;
                $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_image'] = $row->preacher_image;
                $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_logo'] = $row->preacher_logo;
                $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_bio_brief'] = $row->preacher_bio_brief;

                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('sermons');
                $this->db->where('preacher_id', $row->preacher_id);
                $this->db->order_by('sort_order ');
                $sermon_array = array();

                $query = $this->db->get();
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    foreach ($query->result() as $row1) {
                        $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_image'] = $row1->sermon_image;
                        $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_title'] = $row1->sermon_title;
                        $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['audio_file'] = $row1->audio_file;
                        $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_description'] = $row1->sermon_description;
                    }
                }
                $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['sermon'] = $sermon_array;
            }
            return $preacher;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Method in controller

```
function list() {

        $paginate_segment = $this->uri->segment(3) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $winner_list = $this->sermon_model->viewAllpreachers(0, null);
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'sermons/index/';
        $config['total_rows'] = ($winner_list) ? count($winner_list) : 0;
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['num_links'] = 4;
        $config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<div>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</div>';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = ' | ';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = ' | ';

        //initialize pagination
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['preachers'] = $this->sermon_model->viewAllpreachers($paginate_segment, $config['per_page']);
        $this->data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['page'] = $this->config->item('APP_template_dir') . 'site/home/sermons_view';
        $this->load->vars($this->data);
        $this->load->view($this->_container);
    }
```

Comment: You're limiting twice.  Do you want to "fallback" to the settings table if a $limit isn't passed as an argument?

Comment: I didn't get u.. can u please explain

Comment: You're limiting the results by 1) an explicit call to $this->db->limit(), as well as 2) the $limit and $offset parameters of $this->db->get().  My guess is that you're passing NULL as the $limit value, and I have no idea what CI does with that.

Comment: I got the below query after executing that  function.                                                                     SELECT DISTINCT `preacher`.`preacher_id`, `preacher`.`first_name`, `preacher`.`last_name`, `preacher`.`preacher_image`, `preacher`.`preacher_logo`, `preacher`.`preacher_bio_brief` FROM (`preacher`) JOIN `sermons` ON `sermons`.`preacher_id`=`preacher`.`preacher_id` ORDER BY `preacher`.`sort_order` LIMIT 7

Comment: 1st limit is for pagination  $limit=null

Comment: Ok, one thing at a time I guess.  Does the LIMIT 7 there actually result in 8 items in your $preacher array?

Comment: I wonder if there's something funky going on with selecting DISTINCT.  Have you tried grouping on preacher_id instead?

Comment: I think this is the problem with LIMIT. It was working properly before i've given  $this->db->limit($count->settings_value);

Comment: What it sounds like you want is to set $limit to the preacher_count setting value only if $limit is_null(), then you can remove that line again.

Comment: i put  if($limit == ''){
        $this->db->limit($count->settings_value);
        } but no effect..

Comment: Instead of `$this->db->limit(...` in the IF statement, try `$limit = $count->settings_value`

Comment: Nevermind.  You already accepted the answer below.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you're using a limit twice and need to combine those methods:

```
function viewAll($offset=0, $limit=null) {

    $this->db->select('settings_value');
    $this->db->from('site_settings');
    $this->db->where('settings_name', 'preachercount');
    $count = $this->db->get()->row();

    // now use value of [$count] if [$limit] is null - else use [$limit]
    $limit = (is_null($limit)) ? $count : $limit ;

    $preacher = array();
    $this->db->select('...');
    $this->db->distinct('preacher.preacher_id');
    $this->db->from('preacher');
    $this->db->join('sermons', 'sermons.preacher_id=preacher.preacher_id');
    $this->db->order_by('preacher.sort_order');
    // then remove the [limit()] call
    // $this->db->limit($count->settings_value); <-- NOT NEEDED
    $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);
```

This effectively allows you to pass a `$limit` to the method, or use the settings from the db.